# Is there any alternative in tailwind to implement hover, focus etc state instead of writing it repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am new to tailwind CSS and want to customize a button like when a user hover over it, it shows some action. But the utility-classes became very big as I have to write **hover:** again and again. Is there any way, to grouping them into one **hover:**

```
<button class="bg-gray-300 text-black hover:bg-black hover:text-white hover:rounded-sm hover:underline hover:font-semibold">Click Me</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: Right now there is nothing to my knowledge of this kind in Tailwind for inline styles.

However, Windi CSS does have variant grouping which does what you're looking for https://windicss.org/features/variant-groups.html but I think it's still only compatible with Tailwind 2.0.

Comment: You can use `clsx` to split this into multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Tailwind CSS doesn't have any associated syntax, so I created a new CSS language https://css.master.co

### Group Styles

```html
<ul class="{block;p:16;w:full;text:center;font:blue/.5}>li:hover@md"></ul>
```

[View the Group Styles Syntax Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpVps.png)

### Abstracted into a class (v2)

```js
/** @type {import('@master/css').Config} */
export default {
    classes: {
        btn: 'bg:blue bg:blue-55:hover bg:blue-60:active font:semibold font:14 p:10'
    }
}
```

Apply it:

```html
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
```